# I have just added MapKit to my app and have a mapView with an overlay of a route taken, how do I save the mapView with the overlay as an image?

Tags: swift

As a beginner in swift and app development, I have searched for a solution but cannot find anything.
My app tracks the route walked or run and I need to save the result of the walk with an image of both the mapView and the route, together with the distance etc.
any guidance would be appreciated.
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return a `UIImage` of any view you need, including your `MapKit` view. Just call it before you dismiss your controller.

```swift
extension UIView {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
}
```

To call it use

```swift
let image = mapView.snapshot()
```

Comment: This totally worked, thanks very much for your help.